# How do I handle an omnipotent NPC as a DM?

Tags: gm-techniques, npc

I'm roleplaying for more than half my life now, mainly as a player, DMing only a few one shoots. My regular group and I are playing a D&D 5E campaign that will soon come to an end, and our DM is planning a new campaign after that.

In between the regular DM's campaigns, I plan to run a short one. I really wanted play in a certain part of the DM's homebrew world. He said it's all right and I can actually define parts of the lore for that region.

While planning, I had the idea for an NPC, that "rules" its own demiplane - he is omnipotent and omniscient, but trapped inside it. Other people can enter and leave the demiplane without even knowing (it may be the interior of a building).

The plan was that this NPC was malicious, and he likes drama and showing off. He has built a cult around himself. He gets "killed" by the players as part of destroying the cult. He allows it, because he got bored with his cultists and is intrigued by the PCs - he wants to show off his powers. So he rises from the dead and talks to them. He would be some sort of information pool, since he knows everything everyone else in his demiplane has ever known. I imagine him something like an (chaotic) evil Djinn.

My fear is that such a character would not be convincing enough without scaring the players away, since he would be unpredictable.

How should I handle an omnipotent NPC? How can I get the players to interact with him without being afraid of just getting erased from existence?

Gods are mostly bound to their aspect or behave in an expected way (good, bad, chaotic, deviously, militaristic, etc). This NPC wouldn't have such a codex of behavior and could act in random ways.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the omnipotent NPC that you are finding difficult to handle?

Comment: The campaign will be playing in an Arabian themed part of the world, that abandon religion for magic knowledge.  So 1. he is ment as some sort of Disneys Aladdin Dinner replacement, second as he is pretty old knows the old secrets of this land.

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53042/how-do-i-gm-a-character-immeasurably-more-intelligent-than-myself/53052#53052

Answer (score 3):

### Ultimate Cosmic Power; Itty-bitty living space

As you stated, this NPC is restricted to this "plane of existence". The party are free to come and go as they please, yet the NPC is stuck there. The best way to give the party a sense of security is to let them know that this is the case - if they leave, they are safe.

But what's stopping them from leaving and never coming back? Again, you have said that this NPC is "bored", and its interest in the party is a motive to get them to stay - therefore "befriending" the party (regardless of ulterior motives) would be the way to do this. Allow them to *feel* like the NPC is their friend, maybe even bribe them with a magical gift or two (if the DM is ok with it - you don't want to make the party overpowered for their next adventure). Once they feel comfortable coming and going, that's when you can spring your trap.