# How to deal with erotic role play (ERP) frequency in a non-ERP setting?

Tags: sexuality

I am a relatively new roleplayer (been doing it for almost 5 months only) and I have just left my roleplay with the main group I joined. I was roleplaying in Terraria, by the way.

Why did this happen?

Well, things got awkward. *Real* awkward. it was supposed to be a war / drama server, but instead the war was completely halted and instead, there was what I can only consider a glorification of erotic role play (ERP) ripe with promiscuity and hedonism. While those interested in it were always, and I want this to be very clear, **extremely respectful** in how they did it — not even **once** have I seen ERP in public channels — the overall … "feel" of the server started to get really awkward for me. In the end, it was a situation that had my last living character likely getting involved into forced ERP — which again was very well respected, they even gave me the option to essentially disconnect and not really have to go through with the ERP itself — that overflowed my cup.

Because after that happened, and even though ERP didn't even canonically occur (with or without me present), I just feel very very uncomfortable playing my character.

In the end, I said my goodbyes and left the server a few hours ago, likely for a long time if not for good.

Is this a common problem? How do you more experienced folk handle unwanted ERP?

Comment: I made a meta for it, as I feel this question is on topic: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/are-questions-about-roleplaying-within-a-different-context-such-as-a-videogame

Comment: If there isn't a GM or DM, and this is run in an electronic world, that does not necessarily disqualify this question as there are GM-less RPG's.   This [question looks related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/208/22566), but maybe not all that strongly. Most others address at table dynamics and not making people uncomfortable.

Comment: @user27601 It looks like your problem solved itself by you leaving the game.  I am a little unclear what the problem is that you want solved in answering this question.  Is it your intention to participate in such a game in the future, armed with (_something_) which you'll get from an expert/experienced answer here?

Comment: Definitely not the right close reason, but the question is unclear. Do you need help in declining unwanted RP? Coexisting with people doing RP that makes you uncomfortable while doing other types of RP? It sounds like ERP was a core focus of the server in question,  in which case leaving was the best bet (as with any game whose core focus is something you don't want to do), but if you can be more specific,  there may still be a question here.

Comment: This question is both clear and on-topic. The system and the context doesn't matter - the question is pretty clear cut: *how one should handle unwanted ERP*.  That's not different than asking how to handle rape in D&D 3.5 or whatever other system.

Comment: @ThalesSarczuk I strongly disagree. The context *does* matter, and it *is* different. There's a **huge** difference between how you respond to unwanted ERP by *random Internet strangers* vs by *people in the room with you* who are (presumably) your friends.

Comment: @TSar well, to be true the question is not "How do you handle it" but "Did it happen to you?"

Comment: @Zachiel You have a perfectly valid point there!

Comment: @ObliviousSage There is a difference, so it’s important to know the context when answering, but I’m not sure that it matters with respect to topicality on this site. While it may have taken place within some computer game, the *question* is purely about roleplaying. As such, it seems far more appropriate here than anywhere else on the Stack Exchange network—I wouldn’t necessarily expect roleplaying experts at Arqade (and even though I’m sure there are, I *would* expect them to also be members here). Electronic chat through via a game server is little different from other electronic chat.

Comment: I changed the close reason to “unclear what you're asking”, for posterity's sake ([see reasoning in this meta answer](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/6175)).